# Multiple conditions on parameterset

Tags: powershell

In a function, I have 2 `[String]` parameters, `$DBServer` and `$ServiceServer`

Both should be allowed to be blank or filled, but nothing inbetween.

Is this possible to do with parametersets?

Or should I include a check in my PowerShell function which makes sure that my conditions are made?

Comment: ``Both are allowed to be blank or filled, but nothing inbetween.`` whats in between? O_o

Comment: Where `$DBServer` is a value, and `$ServiceServer` is blank or `$ServiceServer` is a value and `$DBServer` is blank.

Comment: ah, okay, the wording was super confusing in your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do this with [Parameter Sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx). So you'd have 2 sets. One in which both parameters are Mandatory, and one in which both parameters are *absent*.

```
function Ruin-Database {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Blank')]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='Filled',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $DBServer ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='Filled',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $ServiceServer
)

    If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Blank') {
        Write-Verbose 'Blank' -Verbose
    } else {
        Write-Verbose 'Filled' -Verbose
    }
}
```

Once you define the function this way, look at the help to see both parameter sets:

```
Get-Help Ruin-Database
```

### Explanation

If a parameter specifies one or more parameter sets, then it will only be included in those sets. If it doesn't specify, it will be included in all sets.

PowerShell must be able to unambiguously resolve the set if you want it to work, so sometimes it takes some trial and error.

One thing you can do to help this is to specify a `DefaultParameterSetName` in the `CmdletBinding` attribute. But you can also specify a parameter set name there that you haven't used in any other parameter. That means the default set would only include parameters that don't specify any set (are available in all), even if there are none of those.

Running help on a function/cmdlet is a good way to see what sets PowerShell is interpreting, as it can get complex.

You can specify multiple `[Parameter()]` attributes on a single parameter to define different characteristics in different sets, for example, a parameter may be mandatory in one set, but optional in another. It may be specified via pipeline in one set, but not in another.

Comment: Good job, I missed the DefaultParameterSetName to solve it :-)